# Defining a System

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:

You decide to drive the 2800 miles from New York to Los Angeles in a hybrid vehicle. A hybrid vehicle has two modes: using only the electric motor and battery, it can travel 1 mile on 3 units of battery power; using only the internal combustion engine, it can travel 1 mile on 0.1 liters of gas (about 37 mpg) while also charging the battery with 1 unit of battery power. At the end of your trip, you have 1400 fewer units of battery power than you did when you began the trip. How much gasoline did you use (in liters)?

You should define a system with the following dimensions:

- net change in the total units of battery power;
- total liters of gasoline used;
- total number of miles travelled;
- number of miles travelled using the electric motor and battery;
- number of miles travelled using the engine.

You should define a matrix M ∈ $R^{3x2}$ to characterize this system. Then, write down an equation containing that matrix (and three variables in R), and solve it to obtain the quantity of gasoline.

Not really sure how to create the matrix. Confused on how to approach because it doesnt state how many miles traveled on battery, and you cant calculate that because gas charges the battery.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the number of miles travelled using the engine and $y$ the number travelled using the electric motor and battery. You use $3y$ units of battery power and restore $x$ units, so your net change in battery power is $x-3y$, which you’re told is $1400$ units: $x-3y=1400$. Of course you also immediately have the equation $x+y=2800$. Notice that those two equations are already enough to let you solve for $x$ and $y$. Finally, you know that it used $0.1x$ litres of gas, so once you have $x$, you also have the answer to the question.

There’s no real need to set this up as a matrix equation in order to solve it. However, it’s not hard to do. The three rows of the matrix correspond to net change in battery power, distance travelled, and gas used, and the columns correspond to the two modes, gas and electric. The first two rows correspond to the system

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&x-3y=1400\\
&x+y=2800\;,
\end{align*}\right.$$

and the last takes care of the gas consumption:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
1&-3\\
1&1\\
0.1&0
\end{bmatrix}\;.$$

Then

$$M{x\brack y}=\begin{bmatrix}
1&-3\\
1&1\\
0.1&0
\end{bmatrix}{x\brack y}=\begin{bmatrix}
x-3y\\
x+y\\
0.1x
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1400\\
2800\\
t
\end{bmatrix}\;,$$

where $t$ is the total amount of gas used. Solving the equation

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-3\\
1&1\\
0.1&0
\end{bmatrix}{x\brack y}=\begin{bmatrix}
1400\\
2800\\
t
\end{bmatrix}$$

then does the job, albeit after a lot of unnecessary work.